# Extracting data from SQL Server using pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

```
import subprocess
import pyodbc

c = dbconn.cursor()
server = r".\SQLEXPRESS01"
database = "test"
dbconn = pyodbc.connect("driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};server=" + server + "; database="+ database +"; trusted_connection=yes;",
        autocommit=True)


\\unable to write code for table name loop \\


    out_path = f"D:\\Projects\\ReferenceModel\\DataFiles\\IN_Download\\Format_Files\\{table_name}.fmt"
    bcp_command = f"bcp {table_name} format nul -c -t, -f {out_path} -S {server} -d {database} -T"
    cmd_args = f"/c {bcp_command}"
    subprocess.call(["cmd.exe", cmd_args])
```

I am trying to extract table names (suppose 50 tables) of all tables in my database `test` using pyodbc, but I'm having trouble doing that. I am trying to get table names from database (`test`) in such a way that I don't have to hard-code it (like I am doing now). Can anyone help me with the code?

Note: trying to use the cursor command to move through all the table names in my database

Comment: Please edit your question to include the error message(s) do you get. I suspect part of your problem may be the un-escaped backslash characters in your out_path string literal.

Comment: The code is actually incomplete. I have re-framed the question and made some edits, maybe makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to invoke `bcp.exe` directly rather than trying to use `cmd.exe /c`. This should be all you need...

```py
import subprocess
import pyodbc

server = r".\SQLEXPRESS01"
database = "test"
connection = f"driver={{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}};server={server};database={database};trusted_connection=yes;"
dbconn = pyodbc.connect(connection, autocommit=True)

cursor = dbconn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM sys.tables")

for row in cursor:
    table_name = row[0]
    out_path = f"D:\\Projects\\ReferenceModel\\DataFiles\\IN_Download\\Format_Files\\{table_name}.fmt"
    args = [ "bcp.exe", f"{database}.dbo.{table_name}", "format", "nul", "-c", "-t,", f"-f{out_path}", f"-S{server}", "-T"]
    subprocess.call(args)
```